# Method to replace inefficient building of lists using searchcursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, list

I am new to search cursors, and have them working to build a list of lists - but there must be a better way. Is there a quick way to slice just the three columns (found in field_name_list) that I want from a layer's attribute table?

Here is my current code:

```
updateData = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer_file, field_names=field_list) as toSearchCursor:
            for row in toSearchCursor:
                templist = [row[0], row[1], row[2]]
                updateData.append(templist)
```

**Edit:**

Addressing comments on readability, I supposed my original method could be improved while still being readable - as the *row* object should only contain the data from the columns I wanted, in the order I want, right?

```
import arcpy

updateData = []
field_list = ['col1','col2','col3']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer_file, field_names=field_list) as toSearchCursor:
    for row in toSearchCursor:
        updateData.append(row)
```

Cleaner, and simpler, and still set to work right?

Also, the list comprehension could be made more clear using differently named variables:

```
import arcpy 

field_list = ['col1','col2','col3']

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mydata', field_list) as sCursor:
    data = [row for row in sCursor]
```

Comment: Something to consider. Personally I'm not a big fan of list comprehension as they are difficult to read if one is looking at code and not the author. If you choose to use them then yes they may be slicker (may be even faster?) but you are forsaking readability and if the code is ultimately going to be run/maintained by another person that is more important than shaving off a few micro microseconds. Whilst all the answers below are good responses the one code I can read easily is yours!

Comment: Well technically you don't even need a list comprehension at all for this now that you are only specifying 3 columns. `data = list(sCursor)`

Comment: Really?  No list comprehension or loop?  It grabs the entirety of all three columns, keeping the column structure? Allowing me to access the columns in some kind of expected manner? If so, please add details and make that an answer!!

Comment: @traggatmot, correct.

Comment: @Hornbydd, I agree [`import this` after all :)]. The microseconds only get magnified to a few seconds when you start accessing a few million records; not earth-shattering at all. For a super deep dive, check out [this blog](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List comprehensions work great here (they're also more efficient instead of appending each row to a list):

```
import arcpy
import pprint    

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mydata', "*") as sCursor:
    print("{} fields".format(len(sCursor.fields)))
    data = [r[:3] for r in sCursor]

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Which prints:

```
16 fields
[(1, (-82.74105086093014, 29.281760685861475), 488),
 (2, (-82.66273663664666, 29.167883225401734), 510),
 (3, (-82.65887427512091, 29.052779589492236), 529),
 (4, (-82.62363060775982, 29.04824697249664), 549),
 (5, (-82.48009557540907, 29.070713102947845), 566),
  ...]
```

Unless you are using the other 13 fields, it's more efficient to just pass in the three fields you'll be using. No need to query the entire row.

Edit:
Yes, if you are only specifying your three fields then the best way would simply be:

```
 with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mydata', ["OID@", "SHAPE@XY", "FACILITYID"]) as sCursor:        
        data = list(sCursor)
```

Comment: I cannot tell how specific column names would be queried in your answer. It seems you just grab  the first three?  If I had a list of column names, how would that work?

Comment: @traggatmot, the `field_names` parameter takes a list of field names. Here, I'm using `'*'` to access all fields -- in practice you'll rarely do this. See the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm). For my data, I just as easily could have done `["OID@", "SHAPE@XY", "FACILITYID"]`

Answer (score 1):

A One liner:

```
updateData = [r[0:3] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mydata', '*')]
```

Note also you can use a set comprehension if you only want unique values.

```
updateDataUnique = {r[0:3] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor('mydata', '*')}
```